# Parallax LRF image viewer connection timed out

Tags: laser, range-detector, parallax

I am using USB to R232 Serial interface to communicate with the parallax LRF through LRF IMage Viewer software. I have installed the drivers for RS232 and have also performed the loop back test. But when i connect it to the LRF module and hit connect in the Image Viewer software, I get the error shown in the below image.[image]

I am using Win10 OS. The LRF has a firmware v2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the USBport. We have to use USB2.0
And i also changed from RS232 to USB to UART(CP2102)